# DisplayWizard not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d I'm trying to convert an (old) [Editor script](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/35445-assign-a-material-to-multiple-object) to one that works in c# in version 4.3 that applies a material to multiple objects.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class AssignMaterial : ScriptableWizard
{
    Material theMaterial;

    [MenuItem("Custom/Assign Material")]
    static void assignMaterial ()
    {
        ScriptableWizard.DisplayWizard<AssignMaterial>("Assign Material", "Assign");
    }

    void OnWizardUpdate ()
    {
        helpString = "Select Game Obects";
        isValid = (theMaterial != null);
    }

    void OnWizardCreate ()
    {
        GameObject[] objects = Selection.gameObjects;

        foreach( GameObject go in objects)
        {
            go.renderer.material = theMaterial;
        }
    }
}
```

Since there is no debug output with Editor scripts, coupled with having to re-compile via restarting Unity (I may be wrong on this) means progress is slow. Any ideas why the script wont "assign" the material?